# Wix install per user as admin

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

I have an issue with my wix installer that I'd like some advice with.

I am using wix to create an msi that performs a per user install. Per user is required so that I don't need admin privileges for installation. I have set the installscope = perUser and impersonate=yes on a custom action. This works well unless there is a group policy set to prevent per user installs.  In this scenario can anyone suggest a way for another admin user, who has policy rights to run an msi, to run the installer and still have the custom action write to the logged on users HKCU registry hive.

Hope this makes sense

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you shouldn't have a custom action doing the writing to HKCU. If we knew what you were writing it's possible that the standard WiX registry element could create the entries so you wouldn't need code. Or you could write a WiX semi-custom action that writes the required rows to the Registry table which, despite its apparent complexity, is a more straightforward design.

Impersonated custom actions don't have access to HKCU by default because impersonation does not mean "behave the same as the interactive logged-on user with those credentials". Impersonation means only that you run with the user's credentials. It does not mean that you have the user's profile (registry hive) loaded. The documentation for [LoadUserProfile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762281(v=vs.85).aspx) explains this. So you'd need to do that LoadUserProfile for the installing user. This all gets complicated rather quickly, and is probably the least-good way to write those entries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I understand what you're saying but I don't have a choice on the custom action.  It is a third party component called addin express and it provides an adxregistrator utility that performs the registration.  This has a lot of logic that I wouldnt want to recreate.